# How to dynamically set components expansion property dependent on container's width

Tags: java, swing, layout

I need to build a panel which contains 2 internal panels, ordered left to right, with fixed height and varied width.
The width expansion, or in other words - the x filling wight, is dependent upon the parent container's width. 
The scenario is that up to a certain width of the parent container, I want only the right panel to fill it's needed horizontal space, and from that width to a larger width, only the left panel to expand, and so on.

I tried 2 ways - switching the `GridBagConstraints` of the 2 children panels, or using `BorderLayout` and similarly removing the children and re-add them with the respective `BorderLayout.CENTER` for the expanded component, or `BorderLayout.EAST` (or west).
This switching will be upon the calculation of the result width interval, by using `ComponentResized` calls by adding `ComponentAdapter` to the parent container.
The problem is that the resize events are not sequential - e.g. I receive events for widths: 317, 322, 330, not necessarily for all the numbers in between, and it is triggered only AFTER the components are resized and painted.
This results in a very annoying flickering when we see the panel expanded up to the width it shouldn't.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Could you try to define MAX widht for the component and use the GridBagLayout with appropriate weightX

Comment: Thanks @StanislavL, but this requires resetting the MAX width for each different width interval of the parent container - which means I will still need to use ComponentListener and the event will be triggered too late... The needed maximum width is also changed in the described scenario dependant on the container's width (for example when the container's width is 0-200 px, the left panel does not horizontally expand, 200-400 it does, 400+ it doesn't again...)

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSplitPane . check this code:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;

public class test extends JFrame {

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    test frame = new test();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public test() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);

        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane();
        setContentPane(splitPane);      
        splitPane.setBorder(null);  

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Arijit, but how can I use JSplitPane in a useful manner? I need the children panels expansion property to be changed dynamically...